# Customize User SObject field labels

Tags: sobject, customlabel

How can I customize the custom field labels of the User SObject?

For other SObjects you can use the "Rename Tabs and Labels" setup entry. However, because the User SObject has no Tab, this isn't going to work.

I'd like to change the "Username" field label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know that isn't possible. I think the field can't even be translated with the translation workbench.

Answer (score 0):

You can change custom field label on User, the problem is that you want to change standard field label.

The only way to achieve this is to create VF page, however this will only be changed in this page - in system you will still have standard label